# Sharing data between components with the same type in Angular.js 1

Tags: angularjs

I currently have three components of the same type. For example, I have a component called 'Lister' and I have three Lister components that calls different apis (e.g. listing teachers, students and courses). However, if a component that loads courses want to access data from the component that renders teachers then in this case, what should I do? I've seen few ways but they are all related to sharing information between components with other types (via $scope and $rootScope).

```
  <lister data-ng-cloak api="/teacher" type="teacher"></lister>
  <lister data-ng-cloak api="/student" type="student"></lister>
  <lister data-ng-cloak api="/course" type="course"></lister>
```

This is the current way to use three components. They share common controller and service.

Comment: All the components shared 1 controller?

Comment: yes they have common controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APIs may be different in your case but they have a common controller and service. So, declare three arrays to store teachers, students and courses in the service.

```
app.service('myService', function{
    vm = this;
    vm.teachers = [];
    vm.students = [];
    vm.courses = [];
});
```

have an api call to get the data.

```
vm.getApiData = $http.get(url).then(); // url may be to get above three from api
```

have a function in service to get the lists in to the controller

```
vm.getData: function(val){
   return vm[val]; // value may be teachers, students and courses
}
```

Call the above function from the controller.

```
$scope.teachers = myService.getData('teachers');
$scope.students= myService.getData('students');
$scope.courses= myService.getData('courses');
```

Now, data is ready. Just access it based on your requirement. Just an idea

Comment: This is actually the best way to do it. or you can say its angular way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent object in controller

```
var parent={};
```

Then for all the listers assign value from this parent object so that all your data can be binded to one common object.
eg : `parent.course=value;`

Then they all be sharing data from one common object

Answer (score 0):

In you controller create one object named as `lister` having properties for each different component **:**

```
$scope.lister = {
    "teacherView": "teacher",
    "studentView": "student",
    "courseView": "course",
}
```

and when you call the `setData` method, receive the data to be stored and the key, lets say

```
componentService.setData(data, lister.teacherView)
```

and update your `getData` so you can choose which data you want to get like this :

```
componentService.getData(lister.teacherView)
```

You can create a `service` like this:

```
angular.module('app').service('componentService', function() {
    var d = {};
    function setData(data, key){
        d[key] = data;
    }

    function getData(key){
        return d[key];
    }
})
```